# List with 1:Many related sub list

Tags: 2010, list, custom-list, list-form

I have a list of Projects and I would like each Project to have a several Requirements associated with it.  I made a Requirements list, and added a column to the Project list that is a lookup into the Requirements list, and set that column to allow multiple values.

This seems to be working okay so far, however the built in NewForm for adding new Projects isn't very intuitive.  It lists "all" the items in the Requirements list, and lets people "Add / Remove" them.  Really I would like just a way to "Create" new requirements and have them automatically associated with the Project list.

I could be going about this entirely the wrong way too, so any input is appreicated

Comment: When you say create new requirements, do you mean that people can add from an existing list or that each time they click create, it adds a new item to Requirements list and associates it with the project? (this is important to gauge the feasibility of certain methods)

Comment: @Zork The first is what is is doing now, and the second is exactly what I would like it to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you have a good plan.  If you review these videos, I'm sure you'll get the last part in place:
http://geekswithblogs.net/SoYouKnow/archive/2009/12/08/creating-a-sharepoint-list-parentchild-relationship-ndash-video-remix.aspx

Comment: @brandon Did my answer help you solve your issue?  If so, would you mark this question answered?

Comment: The "Insert -> Dataview" was exactly what I was looking for, thanks!